# Cannot convert JSON to the correct format

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, character-encoding

I'd like to use JSON output from the public Web Service https://api.rbp-zp.cz/1.3/services/district/ but looks like there is a problem with encoding in this case.
AFNetworking use to do conversion in such cases (by specific respondSerializer) like this:

```
var op = AFHTTPRequestOperation (request: request)
        op.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
```

but it fails because of the invalid JSON structure.

I have tried to do conversion myself, but no outcome

```
let rObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(decodedData, options:.AllowFragments, error: nil)
```

When I put manually this JSON from browser to validator http://jsonlint.com, then it says it is in incorrect format.

Strangely enough when I put the JSON message from my log into the validator then the structure is valid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are those ï»¿ signs in the end of json text?

Comment: @Shoaib you tell me :) that's the encoding mess most likely

Comment: Remove "ď»ż" at the end of json text then it is valid json then It will be converted it.

Comment: @Vanya this issue belongs to the server side but I don't know if you have access to the web service code.

Comment: @Shoaib are you sure it is on the server side? I don't have access there but I can let them know that there is an issue about this. Just wanna be sure.

Comment: This is for sure that this issue is from server end. BTW for temporarily you may convert this text to String, removing those signs, and then convert json text to object.

Comment: ok @Shoaib , thank you for advice

Answer (score 0):

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:String]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        var error: NSError?
        let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as? [String:String]
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }
        return json
    }
    return nil
}

let str = "{\"name\":\"James\"}"

let result = convertStringToDictionary(str) // ["name": "James"]

if let name = result?["name"] { // The `?` is here because our `convertStringToDictionary` function returns an Optional
    println(name) // "James"
}
```

In your version, you didn't pass the proper parameters to NSJSONSerialization and forgot to cast the result. Also, it's better to check for the possible error. Last note: this works only if your value is a String. If it could be another type, it would be better to declare the dictionary conversion like this:

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

and of course you would also need to change the return type of the function:

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the case,..I am getting wrong data from the server and wonder if I can do anything about that.

Comment: Check with this add on for crome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so workaround is trimming those funny characters in the end,..don't like it much but works

```
let range:NSRange  = NSMakeRange(0, res.length - 3);
let refinedData:NSData = res.subdataWithRange(range)

let resObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(refinedData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as! NSArray
```

resObject is correctly filled as NSArray now